# Alternative to flexible array member, without dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, flexible-array-member

I was using a flexible array member to define a USB-String descriptor:

```
// defined
typedef struct {
    uint8_t  bLength;
    uint8_t  bDescriptorType;
    uint16_t bString[];
} ATTR_PACKED USB_StringDescriptor;

// declared
#define STR_PRODUCT  L"My Cool Product"
const USB_StringDescriptor __flash manufacturer_string = {
    sizeof(STR_PRODUCT)+2,
    USB_DTYPE_String,       // 0x03
    STR_PRODUCT
};
```

This worked great and allowed the actual string constants to be defined elsewhere for easy changes between projects. But I can no longer use flexible array members because of compiler restrictions. I would like to avoid hardcoding a char array, I basically just need to tack two bytes to the front of a wide character array. Is there any clever way of declaring an array or a pre-processor macro that could accomplish this?

Comment: FYI, the initialization of a flexible array member as you do above is a compiler extension and not permitted by the standard.

Comment: It might be easiest to upgrade the compiler.  You could replace the `bString` FAM with a pointer; it'll use more space, but you can do as you need — unless what you need requires contiguous memory in the structure. If that's the case, you're stuck.  The "without dynamic memory allocation" requirement leaves you with very few useful options.

Comment: FWIW, I've tried several times to make nice, clean C or C++ structures that function as USB string descriptors.  Never had much success, and certainly not enough to justify the hassle of doing it.  In my latest code, I just used `asm` blocks.  It's ugly and marginally unportable, but it's easy, straightforward and clear.  Comment it carefully and move on.  This is not a favorable place to try to use all the great new C++ features to solve an old problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Unfortunately "upgrading" is what got me here. I wrote the proof of concept in C99 using gcc, and now I am trying to migrate it to IAR and pass a bunch of static analysis test. I also do require contiguous memory, unless I want to do a _significant_ refactor of my code. which isn't really worth it right now.

Comment: @DaveM. I'm not surprised, thanks for the input. For now, i did just write out arrays by hand but that makes it a bit hard to modify between different devices.

Comment: @interjay what part is compiler specific? (besides the __flash obviously).

Comment: You're on a very sticky wicket.  You were accidentally using a GCC extension in your PoC, and when you need to port to another compiler which doesn't support the same extension, you are in difficulties.  It is very important to know when you're using extensions so you can make an informed estimate of the risk involved.  GCC is *very* bad about letting you know when you're using extensions (you have to tell it to be `-pedantic`, and even then …).  FAM technology pretty much assumes dynamic memory allocation.  Are your strings — the FAM bit — limited in size?  Can you simply allocate 256 bytes?

Comment: The part of your code that is compiler specific is the allocation of `manufacturer_string` without using dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, I had no idea. I actually had pedantic on, but don't remember any warnings. Maybe I just missed them somehow. I am pretty memory limited, I am just unit testing right now but eventually, it needs to fit into a pretty small bootloader. Allocating some fixed size (probably not 256) and documenting the limitation is probably my best bet if I can spare the room later on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler also... sorry but you lost me on some of the acronyms. What is PoC and FAM? I am trying to read more about this and I am mostly getting results about a mail service in Hawaii which I presume is not what you meant :). Again thanks for explaining, I try to keep away from compiler specific stuff so it is good to know.

Comment: Use `-Werror` as well; that makes sure you don't compile with any warnings (it converts any warning into an error that prevents the compilation completing).  (Acronyms: PoC = Proof of Concept; FAM = flexible array member)  I tried to get your code compiling on a Mac — the wide string literal caused grief "error: wide character array initialized from incompatible wide string".  I didn't get to the point of being pedantic.

Comment: I got sidetracked by some work — it happens occasionally.  I've got an error: `usb97.c:14:22: error: initialization of a flexible array member [-Werror=pedantic]` (error because I used `-Werror`; it would be a warning without that).  I'm using GCC 7.1.0 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6, if it matters (`gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c usb97.c`).  Newer versions of GCC have vastly improved error reporting over older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no way to achieve a struct with flexible size without the use of dynamic memory allocation in a portable way.

However, one of the following two approaches with a fixed size struct might work for you as well:

1. Define the struct such that `bstring` is an array of fixed size; If you have only one `STR_PRODUCT` in your program, you can use it's size. If you have more instances of the struct, define the array with the maximum size you want to allow.
2. Define the struct with `bstring` being a pointer; You can still initialize it with a pointer to a string literal. Note that an object will then not contain all the information in a continuous memory block. If you require continuous memory containing all the information, this approach 2 will not work.

See the following program which demonstrates both approaches:

```
#define STR_PRODUCT_1   L"My Cool Product"
#define STR_PRODUCT_2   L"Another Cool Product"
#define MAX_PRODUCT_STR  "012345678901234567890"

// Approach 1:
typedef struct {
    uint8_t  bLength;
    uint8_t  bDescriptorType;
    wchar_t  bString[sizeof(MAX_PRODUCT_STR)];
} USB_StringDescriptor;

const USB_StringDescriptor manufacturer_string = {
    sizeof(STR_PRODUCT_1)+2,
    0x03,
    STR_PRODUCT_1
};

const USB_StringDescriptor manufacturer_string2 = {
    sizeof(STR_PRODUCT_2)+2,
    0x03,
    STR_PRODUCT_2
};

// Approach 2:
typedef struct {
    uint8_t  bLength;
    uint8_t  bDescriptorType;
    wchar_t  *bString;
} USB_StringDescriptor_V2;

const USB_StringDescriptor_V2 manufacturer_string_v2 = {
    sizeof(STR_PRODUCT_1)+2,
    0x03,
    STR_PRODUCT_1
};

const USB_StringDescriptor_V2 manufacturer_string_v2_2 = {
    sizeof(STR_PRODUCT_2)+2,
    0x03,
    STR_PRODUCT_2
};

int main() {
    wprintf(L"1: %ls\n",manufacturer_string.bString);
    wprintf(L"2: %ls\n",manufacturer_string2.bString);

    wprintf(L"1 ptr: %ls\n",manufacturer_string_v2.bString);
    wprintf(L"2 ptr: %ls\n",manufacturer_string_v2_2.bString);
}
```

Comment: the second approach is wrong as the descriptor which will be transfered over the USB has to have this string as part of the struct, not the pointer to the literal.

Comment: @PeterJ: right, the second approach will not work if one needs continuous memory. I also assumed that this should be the case, but since the OP did not state this as requirement explicitly, for completeness, I added this approach, too. And actually as the second one because I believe that the first one is more appropriate, too. Will leave a note in the answer...

Comment: the name of the defined type is self explanatory I think :)

Comment: I think approach #1 is the best approach, thanks. I am size limited but I think I could spare a few extra bytes and then just document the length limitation of product names, etc.

Comment: @CrustyAuklet I think that macros are best here - no overhead. I will pot in the answer as it is difficult to list in the comment

Comment: @PeterJ your macro answer was interesting but it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @CrustyAuklet I have done a silly mistake, an instea of edit I have pressed delete. But undeleted it. But leave chosen answer on  Stephan Lechner answer please.

Comment: @Stephan Lechner not intentional points stealing - sorry - . Asked OP to do not choose my one.

Comment: @PeterJ: Don't mind! The answer that meets OP's requirements best shall be accepted. That's SO :-)

Comment: @Stephan Lechner Not if I have advertised it in my comment in your answer :).

Answer (score 2):

Other than [Stephen Lechner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45577070/1475978), you can use an external program to generate the string descriptors (and other similar programs), outputting a C source file to be included by the implementation. This makes sense only if you have lots of constants needing massaging.

Note that rather than a structure, you can use an array of `uint16_t` for USB string descriptors. (All you need to know is the byte order on the architecture, so that the length-in-bytes byte is the first byte in memory, too: it is the high byte for big-endian architectures, and the low byte for little-endian architectures.)

As an example, consider the following awk script, **constants.awk**:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    # 0 = little endian, least significant byte first
    # 1 = big endian, most significant byte first
    BYTEORDER = 1

    RS = "[\t\v\f ]*(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)[\t\v\f ]*"
    FS = "[\t\v\f ]+"

    split("", codepoint)
    for (i = 1; i < 128; i++)
        codepoint[sprintf("%c", i)] = i
    # Note: Could add unicode code points U+00A0 to U+FFFF
    #       to codepoint[] array.

    printf "#ifndef   CONSTANTS_H\n"
    printf "#define   CONSTANTS_H\n"
    printf "\n"
    printf "/* Do not edit this file; edit constants.in instead.\n"
    printf "   This file is automatically generated by constants.awk.\n"
    printf "*/\n\n"
}

$1 == "usb_string_descriptor" && NF >= 3 {
    name = $2
    value = $0
    sub(/^[^"]*"/, "", value)   # Remove everything before first "
    sub(/"[^"]*$/, "", value)   # Remove everything after last "
    valuelen = length(value)
    type = 3

    printf "#define  %s_size  %d\n", name, 2*valuelen + 2
    printf "#define  %s_type  %d\n", name, type
    printf "#define  %s_len   %d\n", name, valuelen
    printf "static const uint16_t %s[%d] = {\n", name, valuelen + 1
    printf "    /* \"%s\" */\n", value
    if (BYTEORDER == 1)
        printf "    0x%02x%02x, /* length = %d bytes, type = 0x%02x */", 2*valuelen + 2, type, 2*valuelen + 2, type
    else
        printf "    0x%02x%02x, /* length = %d bytes, type = 0x%02x */", type, 2*valuelen + 2, 2*valuelen + 2, type
    for (i = 1; i <= valuelen; i++) {
        if ((i % 8) == 1)
            printf "\n    "
        printf "0x%04x, ", codepoint[substr(value, i, 1)]
    }
    printf "\n};\n\n"
}

END {
    printf "#endif /* CONSTANTS_H */\n"
}
```

Let's say you have a file, say `constants.in`, describing some of the constants the above scriptlet should define:

```
usb_string_descriptor manufacturer_string_1 "My Cool Product"
usb_string_descriptor manufacturer_string_2 "My Other Cool Product"
```

Have your build machinery run e.g. `awk -f constants.awk constants.in > constants.h`. If you use Makefiles, then

```
AWK := awk

constants.h: constants.in
    $(AWK) -f constants.h constants.in > constants.h
```

should do the trick. (It even causes the `constant.h` header file to be regenerated, if you edit the `constants.in`

In the actual C source file implementation, you just `#include "constants.h"`.

The above will output

```
#ifndef   CONSTANTS_H
#define   CONSTANTS_H

/* Do not edit this file; edit constants.in instead.
   This file is automatically generated by constants.awk.
*/

#define  manufacturer_string_1_size  32
#define  manufacturer_string_1_type  3
#define  manufacturer_string_1_len   15
static const uint16_t manufacturer_string_1[16] = {
    /* "My Cool Product" */
    0x2003, /* length = 32 bytes, type = 0x03 */
    0x004d, 0x0079, 0x0020, 0x0043, 0x006f, 0x006f, 0x006c, 0x0020, 
    0x0050, 0x0072, 0x006f, 0x0064, 0x0075, 0x0063, 0x0074, 
};

#define  manufacturer_string_2_size  44
#define  manufacturer_string_2_type  3
#define  manufacturer_string_2_len   21
static const uint16_t manufacturer_string_2[22] = {
    /* "My Other Cool Product" */
    0x2c03, /* length = 44 bytes, type = 0x03 */
    0x004d, 0x0079, 0x0020, 0x004f, 0x0074, 0x0068, 0x0065, 0x0072, 
    0x0020, 0x0043, 0x006f, 0x006f, 0x006c, 0x0020, 0x0050, 0x0072, 
    0x006f, 0x0064, 0x0075, 0x0063, 0x0074, 
};

#endif /* CONSTANTS_H */
```

(Note: I seem to recall the USB String Descriptors do not need a terminating NUL character (0). I might recall wrong.)

I used awk, because it is available for all platforms in various flavors -- not just GNU awk, but nawk, mawk, and [many more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk#Versions_and_implementations). You'll want to use a scripting language that yields an easy-to-maintain script; the above version is intended to be extensible to other types besides USB String Descriptors.

I suspect that a Python script may be easier to maintain in the long term, as it is wildly more popular than awk (or Perl, another typical scripting language used for this kind of preprocessing). Plus, Python has the [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) built-in function you can use, and allow you to use non-ASCII Unicode characters in your USB String Descriptors.

Comment: IMO you took a sledgehammer to crack a nut. How many descriptors you have in one device? One, two, maybe three or four as maximum. It does not have to be portable or platform independent :)

Comment: @PeterJ: No, not really; I love my Teensy microcontrollers, which have a native USB interface (no USB-to-serial bridge), so they can become any kind of USB device I want. I also like bare metal coding on them (non-Arduino environment). While the GNU C tools do allow one to construct all the constants needed, it actually is easier to let an external program construct the C sources for those constants. That way, you can easily inspect and verify they are correct (unit testing), while keeping maintenance easy. So, it only *looks* like a sledgehammer! :)

Comment: I do almost only the bare metal programming. And your way has a very important drawback. It is very difficult to experiment. Everytime you need to build C files with constant definitions instead of changing one or two lines. @Nominal Animal it is not a problem of course if you are so good that you do need not change anything or test - and your descriptors are correct form the beginning. I am not -  I do mistakes and often need to change something.

Comment: @PeterJ: I bet I make more errors than you do! That exactly was the reason I included the Makefile snippet. That way, whenever I change anything -- even just the string contents in the `constants.in` file, `make` will do all the head-scratching for me, and rebuild and recompile all affected files. (I do need to include a list of generated header files in prerequisites for each target, but at least GNU Make has all the string manipulation commands to make that trivial.)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if your compiler does not support this type of initialisations the best way is to use macros (I am not the fan of long multiline macros but if there is no other way)

```
#define STR_PRODUCT  L"My Cool Product"

#define USB_desc(name, bL, bD, bS) struct { \
    uint8_t  bLength; \
    uint8_t  bDescriptorType;  \
    wchar_t  bString[]; \
} name = {bL, bD, bS}

USB_desc(manufacturer_string, sizeof(STR_PRODUCT) + 2, 3, STR_PRODUCT);
```

Comment: The problem is that bString will then be allocated two extra bytes, for the null terminator in STR_PRODUCT.